# Configuring old router as repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

I have been at it for about two days and let me give a detailed account of all the settings that I have set.

For the sake of clarity I will call the router which as Internet connection (WAN) as the **mainRouter** and the old router which I want to use as a repeater as the the **secondRouter**.

In the screenshots I have the SSID of the mainRouter as **iball100** and that of the secondRouter as **iballRep**

**Here are the settings for the mainRouter**

[image: Main router settings]

**And now for the Settings for the secondRouer**

[image]

The problem that i have is that the secondRouter does not have access to the internet. When I connect to the secondRouter it says "connected,No internet".
I have tried connecting to it using my phone as well still get the same thing.

The secondRouter doesn't show as a connected client on the mainRouter, is a thing that I observed.

I have no clue as to what am I missing here. The settings that I have work well for youtube videos which I saw, [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21tRWUvsQ34&).

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: What does it offer as system mode?

Comment: I myself have been down this path.  Doing this depends on the router.  Does this router claim to support acting as a repeater/extender?  Many routers will only take the internet from a wired port in the back.

Comment: How are the two routers connected? What is your topology?

Comment: Whats the make/model & version numbers on the underside sticker? Both routers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual for the second device: iB-WRX150NE,
it does not have a repeater mode. It can act in Wireless Router mode or Wireless Client Router mode. The Wireless Client Router mode allows you to connect wired clients using this router as a bridge to the other wireless network. It cannot wirelessly provide access and also act as a bridge.

See section 4.5 Operation mode:

https://www.iball.co.in/File/Product/Drivers/iB-WRX150NE%20User%20Manual.pdf

Comment: The mode is not available as you said, but the WDS option is and that is what makes it communicate with other router. I got it working by switching the routers i.e, using the TPLINK C1200 as the secondRouter and using my old Iball router as the mainRouter.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with my esteemed colleague #HackSlash, the device does not seem to support the feature...
Yet, you might want to try a hack which I used with a cisco router a few years back:

1. Back up your current settings -  “System Tools → Backup & Restore”
2. Connect the network cable (RJ45) from the mainRouter to one of the numbered LAN inputs (not the WAN!)
3. Keep the same SSID name (change the channel to 4 - the difference between channels need be at least 3 slots)
4. Change the operation mode from 'Router' to 'WISP' (Wireless Client)
5. Save settings and restart the secondRouter

I cannot test it on your router model, so I cannot confirm it works... If the system behaves strange - restore from  “System Tools → Backup & Restore” and restart.

Answer (score 0):

While this router seems to be decent, I am thinking that it does not support this feature. If none of the suggested fixes work you can try flashing it with DD-WRT. I did not see the device as being supported on this site:

https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices

The actual manufacturer of the device or the firmware may be different than the outside branding. I have done this many times and there are numerous posts on how to configure it. It may be a little much at first, but it becomes easy.

Good luck.